# What is the best way pull values out of an array based on a predefined iterator number?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm super new to programming, so I'm sorry if this is an elementary question.

I have an array of 12 strings, and I'm hoping to iterate through the array to pull data out.

I am hoping to use a compound operator, stored in a variable, to pull strings out of the array until I'm left with 3 total strings.

Then I'd like to store the updated, pared down array to a variable that I can log to the console.

I've tried for & while loops here, but I think I'm screwing up the syntax OR missing a core concept. I know the while loop below is incorrect, but ran out of ideas and couldn't figure out where to go next.

```
    const iteratorNumber = 7;

    const userInputArray = ['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6','string7','string8','string9','string10','string11','string12']

    while (userInputArray < 4) {
        userInputArray += iteratorNumber;
        userInputArray.slice()
    }

    console.log(userInputArray);
```

Comment: Can you please edit your [mcve] so it includes a list of 12 strings, so it resembles what is being asked?

Comment: `while (userInputArray < 4) {`  Are you intending to compare the *length* of the array to 4?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line of code: userInputArray += iteratorNumber

Comment: @jalynn2 let's say iteratorNumber = 7. what I'm trying to do is use a compound operator to iterate to index 6 of the array, pull a value out, then continue iterating on from that point.

Comment: Array elements are accessed directly with an index: UserInputArray[7]. Adding a number to an array doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. Thank you @jalynn2!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var newArray = []
userInputArray.forEach(function(key,value){
    if(key<10){
        newArray.push(value)
    }
})
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, just use `slice`.  `userInputArray.slice(0,10)` is a lot shorter and clearer.